# How get 'field' column after create new column (setColumnDefs) in ag-grid library

Tags: javascript, php

The idea is this, I create a column

```
let columnDefs = context.dataSetTable.myHeader;
columnDefs.push({
    headerName: get_input_name,
    type: 'NUMBER',
    colId: random_generate_id, //get on controller
    valueGetter: function (params) {
        return params.getValue('My_id_col') * 5
    }

});

context.dataSetTable.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
```

As we can see, the data is generated via valueGetter.
Then on click, I collect information and transfer it to another grid, for this I use this

```
        let getBody = []; // get body 
        let ar_col_hide = []; //get header columns
        let get_column_t = context.dataSetTable.gridOptions.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns();

        api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(function (rowNode) {
            getBody.push(rowNode.data);
        });

        get_column_t.forEach(col=>{
            if(col.userProvidedColDef.headerName !== '#'){
                ar_col_hide.push(col.userProvidedColDef);
            }
        });
```

Next, Im sending this to another grid.
But, my Grid does not see the value (field) of my new column, it sends a header without a body and in the new grid I only see the title (
Grid sees only the incoming array.

I ask for any help, because first time using ag-grid.
TY)

Comment: I do setColumnDefs(), but i can't get field, may be generate json massive ?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Please state clearly what you are trying to achieve and provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I tried to explain more clearly )